# How to copy individual objects between S3 buckets quickly / in a fast manner?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

We have a lambda that is triggered for some S3 files and is supposed to copy them to a different bucket. Basically the code looks  like

```
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    boto3.client("s3").copy_object(Bucket="target-bucket", Key="5_gb.data", CopySource={"Bucket": "source-bucket", "Key": "5_gb.data"})
```

Knowing that a `CopyObject` operation does not actually download the object into the lambda and uploads it again but instead the copy is handled entirely by S3 I would expect this to be done pretty quickly. **But** the lambda (configured with e.g. 1024MB RAM) times out after 15 minutes and the object does not appear in the target bucket.

If I copy the object via

```
aws s3 cp s3://source-bucket/5_gb.data s3://target-bucket/5_gb.data
```

the copy finishes after roughly 2.5 minutes.

Why is the python code so much slower than the `aws` cli call?

Comment: Is that all that the Lambda function does? You could instead use [S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html) to copy new objects to a different bucket.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am aware of replication, have not used it yet and am unsure if it fits our specific usecase. We would certainly need to dynamically adjust the settings since the target buckets are dynamic and new ones can appear at any given time. The existing system is already implemented using the lambda approach, not looking at changing that right now but maybe in the future. Thanks for the pointer regardless.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein S3 Replication requires versioning to be enabled on the buckets. That is not an option for us since at least the target bucket is created by a 3rd party application (data lake) and versioning is not available there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy operation is handled by S3 internally but is quite slow for larger files.

The cli itself uses boto under the hood as well but it uses a different method of copying files, it uses the multipart upload / copy operation and copies parts of the file in parallel (at least as long as the file is large enough) thereby achieving far higher copy performance.
If you inspect the aws-cli code you can see that it uses the `TransferManager` from boto, you can do exactly the same and rewrite your lambda to be:

```
import boto3
from s3transfer.manager import TransferManager, TransferConfig

def handler(event, context):
    manager = TransferManager(boto3.client("s3"), TransferConfig(max_request_concurrency=20))
    manager.copy(bucket="target-bucket", key="5_gb.data", copy_source={"Bucket": "source-bucket", "Key": "5_gb.data"}).result()
```

That will result in the lambda achieving copy speeds that are similar to the local cli invocation. In my testing it was sufficient to provision a lambda with 512MB RAM and it copied the file without getting close to the timeout.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish yes, you can post questions with a self-answer to share knowledge with the community. The two were posted at the exact same time, the question screen has an extra checkbox "answer your own question". https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.246825165.874257882.1648710723-26595988.1643275709

Comment: It does seem a bit off-putting sometimes, because in other contexts this is just weird behavior. But it is perfectly fine here, and encouraged. Especially with helpful information like this.